# Embedding Google-Maps: Street View Photo into a Word Doc -OR- Save as: gif / tiff / jpeg

Tags: google-maps, printing, embedding, google-street-view

Need to print a set of letters with custom content (FName, LName, Address, etc.) using "MS:Word: Mail-merge feature" *and* want to embed a street view of the address in question. The request to get the photo should be directly embedded on the page/letter, so that when I print - say 100 letters, the fields listed above get inserted into the letter - *including* the street view of - based on the address.

I could truly use your help in figuring out a way to dynamically *insert the the JS Call to render the correct "street view photo" (for a given address) into a printable document*... Coding is necessary to print 100s.

Comment: Can you please share what you have done so far? :)

Comment: Probably you can look at Google Street View Image API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro. This will generate images and you don't need JS.